# Different Color Density on Different Devices

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-drawable

In my `colors.xml` i have defined the `EditText` behavior as follow

```
    <color name="txtDisableBackground">#888888</color>
    <color name="txtEnableBackground">#585858</color>
```

and applied to the `EditBox` as

```
<EditText android:textColor="@color/editbox_state"/>
```

now the problem is it is being displayed differently on different devices, and the difference is not minute its very much drastic, like on Galaxy S4 it is close to black and in Galaxy duos it is neat to Gray so what can i do to make them look Grey-ish and close to same on both devices?

Regards

Comment: yup sort of but the devices are changed, in my previous question the devices were Samsung and Huwaei but this time both are samsung devices and i think they must be using sort of same rendering tech so....

Comment: It does no matter which devices are you comparing. EVERY DEVICE IS DIFFERENT. This is the only CRUDE reality. Like it or (obviously) NOT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `FF` to both, to avoid transparency:

```
<color name="txtDisableBackground">#FF888888</color>
<color name="txtEnableBackground">#FF585858</color>
```

Comment: Isn't it 100% opaque by default? How would this affect anything? Thanks...

Comment: @NewOverHere: "Isn't it 100% opaque by default?" -- probably, though I avoid six-digit colors. For the cost of four keystrokes and re-running the project, it's worth a shot.